# Sum excel named ranges using multiple criteria and more than one named range

Tags: excel

On a sheet named “intake” there are 5 columns of data. Columns B and C include numbers that are criteria for sales and row E includes the sales data to be summed. I have two named ranges that each include a number of possibilities for these but are numbers that are in the respective rows. “rng” references data in column c and “rng_2” references data in column B. I have a dynamic range for rows that are decided by cells d6 and d7 and currently I use cell e5 do decide a singular value out of rng_2 to use. I cannot figure out a way to have both criteria be arrays.

Here is my code:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT("Intake!E"&D6&":E"&D7),INDIRECT("Intake!B"&D6&":B"&D7),E5,INDIRECT("Intake!C"&D6&":C"&D7),rng))
```

I haven’t found anything using indirect functions and 2 array criteria so I think others could probably use this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. INDIRECT is volatile and should be avoided when possible.
2. The second array, and you can only have two max, needs to be a horizontal array if the first is vertical and vertical if the first is horizontal so use Transpose.

Formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDEX(Intake!E:E,D6):INDEX(Intake!E:E,D7),INDEX(Intake!B:B,D6):INDEX(Intake!B:B,D7),TRANSPOSE(rng_2),INDEX(Intake!C:C,D6):INDEX(Intake!C:C,D7),rng))
```

Comment: The reason i chose to use the indirect function is that as time goes on the data gets larger so using sumif on the HUGE range tasks my computer more than the indirect function does. but i didn't even think about it needing to be set up as a matrix so thank you very much!

Comment: The Index method also limits the range to only that set by D7 and D6, without the need of Volatile functions.  If this worked for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to make the reference named range in the transpose based off of the name in a cell. lets say i have rng_3 and rng_4 in the first cell in a range is there a way to make a drag and drop version that will use those different named ranges without having to retype them in each equation?

Comment: This is one time you will need to use IDIRECT: `TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(D1))` if D1 was the cell with the name of the named range.  INDIRECT should be avoided, but there are time it is the only thing that works, like here. Or when the sheet name is the variable.